# Can not override JQuery slider styles in versions higher than 1.9

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm working with jquery slider and trying to override its styles. In the [doc](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) it is said that one should override the styles of some classes like the ui-slider-hander in addition to other to get the result. I did that, but it looks like it works with jquery 1.9 but not with higher versions. Is there a reason for that ? or should I proceed differently in this case ?

Here is the slider I'm using:

***JS***

```
$("#deplace" ).slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 50,
            step: 5,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $('#deplace a').html('<label>'+ ui.value +' </label>');
              }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="deplace" >
  <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" href="#" id="a_deplace">
  </a>
</div>
```

***css:***

```
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: #222222;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 7.2em;
  height: 2.7em;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 -40px auto !important;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle .glyphicon {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 1px; 
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.ui-corner-all {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -.9em;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  background: #3498db;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  margin-left: -0.5em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-slider a,
.ui-slider a:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exzthy3x/). Changing the version of jquery makes the slider simply disapear.

**EDIT**

For some reasons, overriding slider styles in JQuery higher than 1.9 does not work. So I temporary get back to this version, though I'm still interested in knowing the reason.

Comment: Your CSS seems to work fine when you include it in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exzthy3x/1/. Changing the version of jQuery in the fiddle makes the slider disappear as jQueryUI is only available for jQ1.9.1 in the options

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there a reason for that or is it just like that is jsfiddle platform. The thing is that I have the same problem running on my code. Though I can see the slider, the styles are completely ignored.